# How does one combine proportionality?

Tags: linear-algebra

this is something that often comes up in both Physics and Mathematics, in my A Levels. Here is the crux of the problem.

So, you have something like this :

$A \propto B$ which means that $A = kB \tag{1}$

Fine, then you get something like :

$A \propto L^2$ which means that $A = k'L^2 \tag{2}$

Okay, so from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that they derive :

$$A \propto BL^2$$

Now how does that work? How do we derive from the properties in $(1)$ and $(2)$, that $A \propto BL^2$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not true in general. For exampe, if $r,A,V,m$ are radius, surface area, volume, and mass of a ball, then $m\propto V$ (this ways introducing the density as factor) and also $m\propto A^{3/2}$ and $m\propto r^3$. But that doesn't imply that $m=kVA^{3/2}r^3$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It works when all factors are independent of each other.

Comment: @Avatar Yes, but that must be formulated as premise about the "state space" or whatever

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I agree.

Comment: In the general case, the implication $(A \propto B$ and $A \propto C) ⟹ A \propto BC$ is **false** as clearly pointed out in Hagen Von Eitzen's comment above and in @ZarifMuhtasim answer below. It is necessary to add the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are independent to make the implication $(A \propto B$ and $A \propto C) ⟹ A \propto BC$ true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $f(a,b)$ being directly proportional to $a$ and $b$ separately imply that $f(a,b)$ is directly proportional to $ab?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4322004/21813)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose a variable $A$ depends on two independent factors $B,C$, then

$A\propto B\implies A=kB$, but here $k$ is a constant w.r.t. $B$ not $C$, in fact, $k=f(C)\tag{1}$

Similarly, $A\propto C\implies A=k'C$ but here $k'$ is a constant w.r.t. C not $B$, in fact, $k'=g(B)\tag{2}$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$f(C)B=g(B)C\implies f(C)\propto C\implies f(C)=k''C$

Putting it in $(1)$ gives,

$A=k''CB\implies A\propto BC\tag{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: How do we know that k=f(C) or k′=g(B) is a fact
Also,
f(C)B=g(B)C which means that f(C)∝C… I didn't get this part... I mean wouldn't that mean that g(B)/B is a constant. Sorry to be a little thick here, but I would deeply appreciate a deeper explanation.

Comment: As i said $k$ is constant w.r.t. $B$ not $C$ therefore it depends on $C$ and hence a function of $C$.

Comment: Oh... now I get that part :) but could you please tell me why f(c) is proportional to C?

Comment: $f(C)B=g(B)C\implies$ $f(C)=\frac{g(B)}{B}C$. Now as you said $\frac{g(B)}{B}$ is a constant $\implies f(C)=$ constant*$C$

Comment: This is the part I didn't get... how is g(B)/B a constant?

Comment: $\frac{f(C)}{C}=\frac{g(B)}{B}$. Since L.H.S. depends only on $C$ and R.H.S. depends only on $B$. Since $B,C$ are independent, therefore, L.H.S.=R.H.S. must be equal to some constant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9475/discussion-between-games-brainiac-and-avatar)

Comment: I am glad, it helped :)

Comment: What do $f(C)$ and $g(B)$ mean here? Functions?

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it does need the additional assumption that $B$ and $C$ are independent.

Comment: **Attention**: This answer is correct only if we assume that $B$ and $C$ do not depend on each other (that is, $B$ and $C$ are independent). Otherwise, it is easy to build a counterexample as @ZarifMuhtasim pointed out. 
Consider that $A= 2B$ and $B=3C$.  Clearly $A=6C$. So $A \propto B$ and $A\propto C$, but it is **not** true that $A \propto BC$. Following the steps of this answer in this counterexample, we can get to $f(C)B=g(B)C$  where $f(C)=1$ and $g(B)=3$. So we can **not** conclude that $f(C)\propto C$.

Comment: In summary: This answer used as a key step that $f(C)B=g(B)C\implies f(C)\propto C$ which may not be true if $B$ and $C$ are not independent.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you are right. We can't prove it.

The following proposition is incorrect:
$(A∝B$ and $A∝C) ⟹ A∝BC$

Let's assume that the above proposition is true. If we can prove that this proposition leads to a contradiction, for any example, then the proposition is incorrect.
Here is a counter-example:
Let's say, $A = 4B$ and $B = 3C$
Therefore, $A = 4(3c) = 12C$
Therefore, $A∝B$ and $A∝C$

Given, the proposition is true, the above statement implies A∝BC
Therefore, $A = kBC = k(3C)C = 3kC^2$
Therefore, $A∝C^2$
Which is a contradiction. Both $A∝C$ and $A∝C^2$ can't be true.

But here is what your Physics and Mathematics books tell you.
$(A=k'B$ and $k'=k''C) ⟹ A∝BC$
And we can prove it very easily
$A=k'B=(k''C)B=k''BC⟹ A∝BC$

Comment: k’=k’’C is not given as an assumption in the question. So have you assumed this yourself because it is necessary to solve this question

Comment: @aaksaksyk yes.

Comment: @aaksaksyk Without any additional assumption, the implication $(A∝B$ and $A∝C) ⟹ A∝BC$ is **false**, as Zarif has pointed out.

Comment: Are you saying that $A \propto C$ and $A \propto C^2$ can both *never* be true? If you let $A = k_1 C$ and $A = k_2 C^2$, this implies that either $C = 0$ or $C = \frac{k_1}{k_2}$. So while it is not *always* true, it looks like it can be true under very specific conditions.

Comment: @Mailbox $(A∝B$ and $A∝C) ⟹ A∝BC$ given B is dependent on C will not hold for an infinite number of cases except the two you mentioned. If it doesn't hold for even one case, the statement would be considered invalid. So yes, it is true under very specific conditions, but the fact that it is not _always_ true makes the statement false.